# Refactor code that includes "double pipe" and "instance variable" using metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have two methods:

```
def ios_ids
  @ios_ids ||= Array(GcmToken.find_by(users_id: "#{@event.user_id}", os_type: 'ios', alive: true).try(:reg_id))       
end

def android_ids
  @android_ids ||= Array(GcmToken.find_by(users_id: "#{@event.user_id}", os_type: 'android', alive: true).try(:reg_id)) 
end
```

I want to refractor them in to something like below

```
%w(android ios).each do |os_type|
  define_method(:"#{os_type}_ids") { "@#{os_type}_ids" ||= Array(GcmToken.find_by(users_id: "#{@event.user_id}", os_type: os_type, alive: true).try(:reg_id))}
end
```

But It doesn't work

Anyone have any answers or better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [Object#`instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) and [Object#`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get):

```
%w(android ios).each do |os_type|
  define_method "#{os_type}_ids" do
    instance_variable_get("@#{os_type}_ids") ||
    instance_variable_set("@#{os_type}_ids", Array(GcmToken.find_by(users_id: "#{@event.user_id}", os_type: os_type, alive: true).try(:reg_id)))
  end
end
```

Comment: @Ilya typo, of course you're right, thanks for spotting!

Comment: should I delete my answer?)

Comment: @Ilya in such cases (when you see someone has made a minor/style mistake in his answer) you should probably rather edit the already given answer instead of providing a new one with just better code presentation. This is IMO and I do not claim it to be a rule or anything, just my vision of common sense :)

Comment: It wasn't `just better code presentation`. Please, compare `instance_variable_set(:foo, instance_variable_get(:foo) || something)` and
`instance_variable_get(:foo) || instance_variable_set(:foo,  something)`. So, I desided to do like I did)

Comment: It looks similar, I agree, but it's totally different ways.

Comment: @Andrey Deineko you give a right answer, thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

Using that kind of metaprogramming is really heavy-handed, especially when manipulating instance variables like that. Normally when you go down that path it's because you've got a *lot* of situations like that which need to be tidied up.

Let's tackle this in smaller steps:

```
def ios_ids
  @ios_ids ||= Array(GcmToken.find_by(users_id: "#{@event.user_id}", os_type: 'ios', alive: true).try(:reg_id))       
end
```

There's some really odd stuff happening here, like the `"#{x}"` anti-pattern, that's quoting a single value which is almost always pointless. In cases where you absolutely need a string, use `.to_s` on the value in question.

This also loads the model and tries to fetch an attribute from it. That's extremely wasteful. It also packages it up using the irregular `Array(...)` notation which is rarely used. `[ ... ]` is preferred.

So cleaning this up a little you get:

```
def ios_ids
  @ios_ids ||= GcmToken.where(
    users_id: @event.user_id,
    os_type: 'ios',
    alive: true
  ).pluck(:reg_id)
end
```

That boils it down a lot. Now it's just fetching all of the associated `reg_id` values from that `GcmToken` model. If you have a `User has_many :gcm_tokens` and `Event belongs_to :user`, which should be the case given the data here, then you can clean it up even more:

```
def ios_ids
  @ios_ids ||= @event.user.gcm_tokens.where(
    os_type: 'ios',
    alive: true
  ).pluck(:reg_id)
end
```

You can clean this up even more with a simple `scope` declaration:

```
scope :alive_for_os_type, -> (os_type) {
  where(os_type: os_type, alive: true)
}
```

Then it becomes even smaller:

```
def ios_ids
  @ios_ids ||= @event.user.gcm_tokens.alive_for_os_type('ios').pluck(:reg_id)
end
```

That's getting pretty small. At that point reducing this with `define_method` is over-kill, but if you really want to, then do this:

```
OS_TYPES = %w[ android ios ].freeze

OS_TYPES.each do |os_type|
  method_name = "#{os_type}_ids".to_sym
  instance_var = "@#{method_name}".to_sym

  define_method(method_name) do
    instance_variable_get(instance_var) or
      instance_variable_set(
        instance_var,
        @event.user.gcm_tokens.where(
          os_type: 'ios',
          alive: true
        ).pluck(:reg_id)
      )
  end
end
```

That ends up being significantly more mess and code than just boiling down the implementation of each to a more minimal form. If you had dozens of types maybe you'd want to do this, but honestly, what about this:

```
def platform_ids(os_type)
  @platform_ids ||= { }

  @platform_ids[os_type] ||= @event.user.gcm_tokens.alive_for_os_type(os_type).pluck(:reg_id)
end
```

One method that can handle N types, all you have to do is specify which one. Sometimes special-purpose methods aren't worth the fuss.

Comment: you give a right answer and many suggest, thanks for your help.I will study your suggest seriously.

Comment: Hi,I read the article that say we should use interpolate instead of to_s, can you solve my confuse that what situation should I use to_s or interpolate?

Comment: The article is here [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-solve-coding-anti-patterns-for-ruby-rookies/)

Comment: @tsao That's for interpolating within a string where the pattern is `"...#{x}..."` but having a variable in isolation is pointless. For example, do `puts "Hello #{name}"` but don't do `puts "#{name}"`.